# Youtube JavaScript API isn't initializing

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, initialization

Using YouTube's JavaScript API to control an iFrame embed. I've set up the functions and don't see any errors... but I'm not logging the API's initialization as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#EventHandlers).

Yes, it's running off a server, not locally: http://jp.redwoodmatthews.com

Am I missing something? HTML and JavaScript below! Thanks for your help.

---

iFrame HTML:

```
<iframe id="ryanBingham" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Xz5SNppHRxc?rel=0?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=video" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    video = document.getElementById('ryanBingham');

    video.addEventListener('onStateChange', 'onytplayerStateChange');

    console.log('YouTube API initiated');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the wrong API docs. This is for iframes: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Due to same origin restrictions, it works a bit differently. Also, the ready function is named `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`.

Last but not least, make sure you [load the API JS file](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started)